# Javascript XML documentation regex

Tags: javascript, xml, regex

I am creating a small library for parsing XML documentation in Javascript files in the following format:

```
/// <doc type="function" name="parse">
///     <summary>Parses javascript documentation</summary>
///     <param name="js" type="string">Javascript input</param>
/// </doc>
var parse = function(js) { ... };

/// <doc type="string">
///   <summary>Holding the version of our library</summary>
/// </doc>
var VERSION = '0.0.1';
```

I have to create a regular expression that returns the content between the  and  tags. I've tried the following regular expression but it failed:

```
var xmlComments = js.match(/ \/\/\/(\s)<doc(.*)>(.*)<\/doc>/gi /);
```

But the match did not work, I hope someone can help me with this regular expression, thanks.

Comment: How do you invoke `parse`? In other words: how do you get the doc comment from the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the content between the opening and closing `doc` tags, you could use

```
/<doc[^>]*>([\s\S]+?)<\/doc>/gi
```

where `[\s\S]` is any character including newlines ( `.` will not match newlines ).

For example

```
var xmlComments = [],
    regex = /<doc[^>]*>([\s\S]+?)<\/doc>/gi,
    match = regex.exec( js );

while ( match != null ) {
    xmlComments.push( match[1] );
    match = regex.exec( js );
}
```

where `js` is the file as a string.